# Liferay 7.4 doesn't start as windows service

Tags: java, installation, liferay

i already asked in Liferay forum but i didn't get an answer, i was trying to configure a clean Liferay 7.4 portal to start as a service on Windows Server 2022, i followed the same steps used to configure Liferay 6.2.5 and generic Tomcat servers as a service, and while the latters start without problems, Liferay 7.4 won't start showing the following error:

```
2023-01-18 13:46:05 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized.
18-Jan-2023 13:46:06.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1057] milliseconds
JVM arguments: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68 -Dcatalina.base=C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68\conf\logging.properties exit abort -Xms128m -Xmx256m
18-Jan-2023 13:46:10.657 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6]
    java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4767)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5231)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:583)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.proxy.ContextClassLoaderInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextClassLoaderInvocationHandler.java:43)
        at com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.proxy.EventListenerInvocationHandler.invoke(EventListenerInvocationHandler.java:64)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing storage.
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:248)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing storage.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.EquinoxFactory.newFramework(EquinoxFactory.java:24)
        at com.liferay.portal.bootstrap.ModuleFrameworkImpl.initFramework(ModuleFrameworkImpl.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.module.framework.ModuleFrameworkUtil.initFramework(ModuleFrameworkUtil.java:37)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:236)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\osgi\state\org.eclipse.osgi\.manager\.fileTableLock (Access is denied)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.location.Locker_JavaNio.lock(Locker_JavaNio.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.lock(StorageManager.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:701)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getChildStorageManager(Storage.java:2011)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getInfoInputStream(Storage.java:2028)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:69)
        ... 53 more
18-Jan-2023 13:46:10.657 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
18-Jan-2023 13:46:10.657 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
null
null
BeanLocator is null
18-Jan-2023 13:46:10.704 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6]
    java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.contextDestroyed(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4815)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:583)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.proxy.ContextClassLoaderInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextClassLoaderInvocationHandler.java:43)
        at com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.proxy.EventListenerInvocationHandler.invoke(EventListenerInvocationHandler.java:64)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator is not set
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:68)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.closeDataSource(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:380)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:151)
        ... 49 more
18-Jan-2023 13:46:10.751 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [4150] milliseconds
```

I used this command to install the service:

```
C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68\bin>service.bat install liferay74_59_clean
Installing the service 'liferay74_59_clean' ...
Using CATALINA_HOME:    "C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68"
Using CATALINA_BASE:    "C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\tomcat-9.0.68"
Using JAVA_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211"
Using JRE_HOME:         "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre"
Using JVM:              "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
The service 'liferay74_59_clean' has been installed.
```

If i try to start the portal with startub.bat in tomcat/bin folder all works without problems, so it's something relative to the launch as windows service.

Anyone have an idea of what's going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\osgi\state\org.eclipse.osgi\.manager\.fileTableLock (Access is denied)` My first guess would be a filesystem permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

To run properly, Liferay needs some write permissions on the file system. If you run it (or tomcat) as a windows service, you're typically running under a different user account than you're running interactively. Whichever account it is, *that* account needs write access to a few directories. I wouldn't claim to be exhaustive, but some of them are, under your `${liferay.home}`, which seems to be `C:\Portals\liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.59-ga59_clean\`:

- /deploy
- /osgi
- /data
- /tomcat/temp
- /tomcat/work
- /tomcat/logs
- /logs

Those can be configured to be elsewhere, but you're looking for these directories to typically be writable. Don't blame me if I missed one...